# Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The requested route does not exist: :route ~ APPPATH/ko322/classes/kohana/route.php [ 106 ]

Tags: php, kohana

Any php / mysql specialists have an idea what this error may be caused by.

I've uploaded a script to my server for a classified ads cms and after about 1 month of working fine, I am getting this error now when I go to my url.

> Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The requested route does not exist: :route ~
>   APPPATH/ko322/classes/kohana/route.php [ 106 ]

My url is  e-waitress.net

thanks very much!

Comment: Would you mind showing the contents of that file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DaSourcerer and to Darsstar here is the file in question:

Comment: [link]http://baxterinternet.com/route.txt

Comment: Strange, it seems you Route::get() a non existing route somewhere. I suspect in your registered exception handler. Any changes to the bootstrap.php recently? Could it be your host restored from a backup without informing you? Maybe some form of caching was being used which has been turned off?

Comment: I am going to check with my host, that is likely the culprit because I didn't change anything and everything as working fine up until a couple days ago.

Comment: Here's a link to my Bootstrap.php @Airoude [link]http://baxterinternet.com/Bootstrap.txt

Comment: Is that your entire bootstrap.php? Because if there aren't any routes, Route::get() logically won't find one. The only other place I would be the index.php or one of the not standard files index.php includes. Do a recursive search for 'Route::set' ?

Comment: Customer support was not very helpful at 1and1.com restating the obvious.. But I didn't change anything so it must have been something with the server, the code didn't change itself. I posted the Route:Set here  [link]http://www.baxterinternet.com/routeset.txt

Comment: Thanks to @Darsstar and all for the assist, read below, I just cleaned out the cache, then ran the install folder to get connected back to the server again. I think I should come up with a fancy name as well to use instead of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the cache file that got me into the website but blew out the 'back end' of the database connection to the server, then ran the install folder again, which was successful. Still not sure why the original error message, though I suspect it was server related.

A special thanks for all @Airoude and @Darstar for the yeoman's job of trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Provide the routes in your bootstrap.php

Comment: Here's a link to my bootstrap.php code: [link]http://baxterinternet.com/Bootstrap.txt

Comment: I've found the Route set in the config folder and pasted it here [link]http://www.baxterinternet.com/routeset.txt

Answer (score 0):

delete all files in "cache/" folder